# Debounce to reduce function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, lodash, debouncing

I have an event that sends me download progress and I am saving this progress in the database. Normally I don't need to save all the progress like 1%, 2%, 3% instead I need to save by 2%, 7%, 20%, etc. So instead of calling the database saving function on every event data, I want to call the function in delay like after 3 or 4 seconds.

This is my code snippet but the problem is It's only waiting for 3s on the first even data, It continues on every event data after the first debounce call.

```js
// using `lodash/debounce`
const debouncer = debounce(async (data) => {
  await debounce.save(data)
}, 3000);

event.on('downloadProgress', async (e) => {
  debouncer(e);
});
```

Let me know how you handle this type of situation to reduce the function calling in every event.

Comment: You might be looking for throttle instead of debounce? https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle